# How to show last two rows only in tableview from sqlite using with QSqlQueryModel?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, pyqt5, qtableview, qsqlquerymodel

Below is my example code:

```
db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
db.setDatabaseName('book.db')
db.open()

model = QSqlQueryModel()
model.setQuery("SELECT * FROM card")
self.tableView.setModel(model)
```

I am using QSqlQueryModel, Qtablevie, Sqlite3, and able to view all rows in my table. But i want to view only last two rows of my table which are newly inserted rows in to the table. The table has no "id" field and it has numaric and text fields. How is it possible?
Below is the table image:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the last 2 elements ordered by any field that indicates the insertion order, in your case "rowid", then you have to use a filter in the SQL command like this:

```
model.setQuery("SELECT * FROM card ORDER BY rowid DESC LIMIT 2")
```

Another possible option is to filter the table using QSortFilterProxyModel but it is more inefficient.

Comment: I added Above command but it is showing empty tableview.

Comment: @user3030327 I'm assuming that your table has a numeric "id" field, does it? You could indicate the fields of your table and what type they are.

Comment: Actually it dose not has "id" field. and it have numeric and as well as text fields. If try with "rowid"  It is working , can i use it .

Comment: Okay. I will edit my question that it has now "id" field. you can change the answer. Can i edit?

Comment: @user3030327 I don't understand you, the name "id" is irrelevant, it can be row_id, etc, logic is the most important. use `model.setQuery("SELECT * FROM card ORDER BY rowid DESC LIMIT 2")`. Analyze my answer and don't just do a copy-paste

Comment: @user3030327 If you want more help then share your db as you don't seem to understand my answer

Comment: This is working : `model.setQuery("SELECT * FROM card ORDER BY rowid DESC LIMIT 2")`. And this is not working `model.setQuery("SELECT * FROM card ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2")` which is in your answer.

Comment: @user3030327 mmm, I already adapted my answer to your particular case, are you happy already? The code provided should not be literal as the OP is expected to analyze what is justified and not just copy-paste machines.

Comment: Actually i want to accept your answer that's why  I edited my question and asked you to change your answer. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219964/discussion-between-user3030327-and-eyllanesc).